# Quick Lanch bar and Inno Setup v6

Tags: windows, inno-setup, quicklaunch

My installer started off years ago and thus has a [Quick Launch bar](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?quicklaunch) task.

```
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Public Talks"; \
Filename: "{app}\CommunityTalks.exe"; \
MinVersion: 4,4; \
Tasks: quicklaunchicon
```

When compiling this raises the warning:

> Warning: The `[Setup]` section directive `"PrivilegesRequired"` is set to
>   `"admin"` but per-user areas (`HKCU`,`userappdata`) are used by the script.
>   Regardless of the version of Windows, if the installation is running
>   in administrative install mode then you should be careful about making
>   any per-user area changes: such changes may not achieve what you are
>   intending. See the "UsedUserAreasWarning" topic in help file for more
>   information.

How should we handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "Quick Launch" toolbar functionality from your installer.

No one is using that nowadays. The "Quick Launch" toolbar [was removed in Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar#Microsoft_Windows) (2009).